# Reactjs: Passing component to state value

Tags: reactjs, react-router, navigation, components

I'm trying to create a web app where I want the user to browse around without the use of React-Router. Is it a good practice to pass a component to the state and change it according to what the user clicks? Example below:

```
import Intro from "./Intro"
import Chapter1 from "./Chapter1"

class MainPage extends React.Component {
    state = {
        currentView: <Intro/>,
    };

handleuserActions = (e) => {
        switch (e.key) {
            case "Intro":
                this.setState({ currentView: <Intro/> });
                break;
            case "Chapter1":
                this.setState({ currentView: <Chapter1/> });
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        
    };

render() {
        return (
         <>
         <Menu onClick={this.handleSideMenu}>
                <Menu.Item key="Intro">
                        Intro
                    </Menu.Item>
                    <Menu.Item key="Chapter1">
                        Chapter 1
                </Menu.Item>
         </Menu>
         {this.state.currentView}
         </>  
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing components in state is not considered a good practice. State is meant for data that changes over time, the *render* is responsible for managing UI.

Instead, you can store a boolean or some other data in state that can be used to conditionally render a component.

For example, you could translate it to something like this:

```js
class MainPage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    currentView: 'Intro',
  };

  handleuserActions = (e) => {
    this.setState({ currentView: e.key });    
  };

  renderCurrentView = () => {
    switch (this.state.currentView) {
      case "Intro":
        return <Intro />;
      case "Chapter1":
        reutrn <Chapter1/>;
      default:
        return null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <>
         <Menu onClick={this.handleSideMenu}>
            <Menu.Item key="Intro">
              Intro
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="Chapter1">
              Chapter 1
            </Menu.Item>
         </Menu>
         {this.renderCurrentView()}
       </>  
    )
  }
}
```